# Generate Sql DB Script in C#

Tags: c#

I have a sql table that contains Table Columns Properties like TableName, ColumnName,  Datatype, IsPrimary, IsNullable, DefaultValue, Length etc and also a versionId.
So my requirement is comparing two versionIds and then generating scripts in C# 
like `alter table`.

Please tell me how to do this programatically.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

it is not a simple task by any stretch, the simplest way is to generate scripts for both versions and then do a diff like check - but there is SO much in SQL that can occur that it will require a lot of custom logic to be built.

Visual Studio does include [Schema Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx) which is what you want to build, maybe you can integrate that into your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server, you could shell out using [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) and run the [tablediff Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx)